# Calculated Projected Area of Object From Any Given Perspective

Tags: matlab, graphics

Suppose I have an STL file which consists of vertex and face data for a given object. How can I calculate the area of the ortho projection of the object given any arbitrary orientation without using Matlab graphics, just simple math with as few built-in Matlab functions as possible. Keep in mind that this is different than just a simple silhouette as there can be gaps in the projection that aren't captured by the object outer outline only.

I originally did this by taking the pixel data from the plot and then counted non-white pixels. That worked great but I need to be able to compile the code for use with C but as far as I can tell any graphics/plotting can't be compiled with Matlab coder.

Image below is a good example (see gap between torso and left arm). A torus is also another good example geometry.

[image]

Comment: If you can get the shape of the projected triangles, just calculate the sum of the individual areas.

Comment: Sure but what about overlapping polygons? The area of any overlap will get counted twice when calculating the total.

Comment: you will need to write code to account for that! Once you have all your triangles in 2D, you can then compute also overlap between trianles. This are all polygons, so you will know the area too. None of this is easy to do and a full answer is definetly out of scope of this webpage.